# best way to display data based on the value of an enum table value

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, enums

I would ask an advice about the best way to display DB data on a page based upon the status of the user who has logged on a website.

That's the example: My admin panel has two types of users: administrators and regular users.

When i log in, if the login data is associated to the "regular user", i will only display three menu voices, but if the login data is associated to the "administrator", in the next page (the admin panel), i will display more blocks of data that the regular user can't access. The status of the user who log in is stored in a enum field of the table (regular, admin).

I don't want to do this creating two pages, but i want to understand the best way to approach the problem:

As i'll do a redirect, do i have to make this distinction when i log on (during the Select which allows me to log in or not) or when i'm in the admin panel (the "new" page)? And if i have to do it when i'm in the new page, what's the best way to do it? Making a query?

I wouldn't make a query because i would manage the content loading via Ajax.

Could you give me some tip?